# Python Selenium choose element list

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, wait

```
WebDriverWait(self.browser, 5).until(
            expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "name")))
query = driver.find_element_by_id('name') 
query.send_keys('python')
options_list = driver.find_element_by_xpath('path with element list') 
target_option = WebDriverWait(options_list, 5).until(expected_conditions.presense_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "[text()[contains(.,'python')]]")))
driver.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

This is my code. I should open list and choose 'python', this code is ok when i use time.sleep but in my exercises i can't use time.sleep
My list slow a load and First I write a 'python' and and then the list is loaded.

Comment: Can you sumup the exact _Manual Steps_ which you are trying to _Automate_?

Comment: I click button and moves me to the next page.
I have a form and list of elements. To reduce the list, I enter 'python'. then I want to choose the first element.
The list is large. it loads for a long time. I do not know how to do it correctly. It takes some time from entering the form and loading items.

Comment: Can you provide the code that works using `time.sleep`?

Comment: time.sleep(7) 
WebDriverWait(self.browser, 5).until(
            expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "name")))
query = driver.find_element_by_id('name') 
query.send_keys('python')
options_list = driver.find_element_by_xpath('path with element list') 
target_option = WebDriverWait(options_list, 5).until(expected_conditions.presense_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "[text()[contains(.,'python')]]")))
time.sleep(5)
driver.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

Comment: What output do you see when you run your script without the `sleep()`?

Comment: enters the python string.
the list is only in the process of opening.
He receives a python. but the test did not manage to select the item.

Answer (score 0):

Your code block without the **time.sleep(7)** looks perfect. The changes you need to make are as follows. In the first *wait* as you are sending text you need to change the `expected_conditions` clause from `presence_of_element_located` to **element_to_be_clickable** and in the second *wait* as you are waiting for the text **python** to be visible you need to change the `expected_conditions` clause from `presence_of_element_located` to **visibility_of_element_located** as follows :

```
WebDriverWait(self.browser, 5).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "name"))).send_keys('python')
options_list = driver.find_element_by_xpath('path with element list') 
target_option = WebDriverWait(options_list, 5).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(.,'python')]")))
driver.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```